# Group directories which are symbol links first with ls

Tags: linux, ls

I employed the predicate `--group-directories-first` to display the directories on the top.

However, it take effect singularly on the real directories but excluding the directories which are sym-links.

For example, in the Downloads directory, I make dozens of symlink-directories to facilitate the categories of freshly downloaded file.

How could group directories which are syslinks first?

Answer (score 1):

You can use -L option to group directories with symlink first 
ls -lL --group-directories-first